# Блокировка Объекта для ограничения доступа к его методам(к методам объектов)

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Возникла надобность: ограничить доступ к объекту(только один поток может его использовать). Т.е только один поток может использовать методы и методы его объектов.
Пример кода(вызова методов).

```
var human=new Human("Dima");
var ts=new Task(human.Coat("2").Sleeve.Right.Cut);
ts.Start();
```

Т.е я создаю человека с именем "Dima" и говорю: человек, у второго пальто правый рукав отрежь.
Притом метод Coat обращается к коллекции Coats на время, т.е в Human есть коллекции пустых Coat. При обращении к этому методу мы передаем идентификатор пальто и дальше с ним работаем. Запросы отправляем на сайт.

Загвоздка в том, что все это будет проходить в многопотоке, т.е я могу вызвать 4 похожих метода и вытаскивать из массива рандомный Coat. Если он занят каким-нибудь потоком(например вызвал я Cut()), то ждет, пока поток не отработает. После отработки Coat очищается(точнее идентификатор) и готов к использованию.

Пробовал сделать оператором lock на возвращаемый из коллекции Coat(в виде локера), но это глупо, ибо он возращает это объект и пофиг. Пробовал создать флаг, но в многопотоке фигня получилась. Пробовал еще пару способов, но я их не припомню и они такие же глупые, как и эти.

Думаю сделать так:

```
var human=new Human("Dima");
Coat coat;
        lock (coat=human.Coat("2"))
        {
            var ts=new Task(human.Coat("2").Sleeve.Right.Cut);
            ts.Start;
        }
```

И дальше при инициалзации в объектов(например Sleeve) передавать этот coat и в каждом методе вставлять lock, но попахивает это велосипедом на костыльной тяге... Чувствую, что в теории упускаю очень важный момент, но какой.

Вопрос: как сделать такую вещь? Возможно ли это? Подойдет ли мой способ и как обычно делают подобное?

P.S. Пример абстрактный, насущный код не могу показать.

---

**Обновление**

Подумав на способом выше, понял что опять же не корректно. Если я везде буду расставлять lock(coat), то...

Инициализируем переменную Sleeve и передаем Coat

```
_

sleeve=new Sleeve(this);
Lock на этот Sleeve
    private SleeveClass _sleeve;
    public SleeveClass Sleeve
            {
                get
                {
                    lock (this)
                    {
                        return _sleeve;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Тоже самое с Right

Метод Cut

```
public void Cut()
        {
            lock (_сoat)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Coat {0}",_сoat.CoatId));
            }
        }
```

Может произойти так: есть два потока, один ожидает где-нибудь на изменении данных Coat. Например тут:
public CoatClass Coat(string CoatId)
        {

```
        lock (CoatObj)
        {
         CoatClass CoatObj;            
        _coatPull.TryPeek(out CoatObj);
            CoatObj.CoatId = CoatId;

            return CoatObj;
        }
    }
```

А другой в методе Cut. Может сначала измениться объект Coat в одном потоке, подать сигнал "отработал", а потом заработает Cut и в итоге мы отрежем не у того пальто. Поэтому этот вариант не подойдет, нужно непрерывно блокировать доступ к объектам и полям, он занят каким-нибудь потоком.

---

Использую Concurrent коллекцию. Да, она является потокобезопасной, но суть там в другом(насколько я понял). Частая проблема при работе с коллекцией в многопотоке - одновременная запись и удаление одного и того-же объекта. И эта коллекция как раз дает доступ только одному потоку, что решает эту проблему(и несколько других).В отличие от других коллекция выдает рандомный элемент. Тобишь все коллекции решают проблему работы с ней самой, а не с элементами коллекции.

Comment: "Многопоток" у вас на клиенте или на сервере? Если на клиенте - то зачем?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov работа происходит с сайтом, ошибся.

Comment: Так многопоток-то где?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov поправил

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov спасибо, что откликнулись.

Comment: Добавил содержимое из вашего комментария к удалённому ответу, т.к. этот комментарий проясняет важные дополнительные подробности. Проверьте, может быть что-то можно дополнить или наоборот сократить.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin а можно ссылку на удаленный ответ? Я не забыл о вопросе, просто ещё не сформулировал ответ. Заняло время на поиски ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @Arantler ответ тут, под вопросом, только вы его не увидите - нужно 10000 репутации. Там было "Concurred коллекции не спасут? Посмотри в их сторону".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно эксклюзивное право на владение объектом? Это довольное опасная затея, которая может привести к взаимоблокировке. 
С точки зрения ООП ваш код несколько не логичен. 
Ваш говорите: правый рукав второго пальто Димы - отрежься. 
А следовало бы: Дима, отрежь правый рукав второго пальто. 
Объект не должен знать о том, в какой коллекции он находится. 
Можно воспользоваться [блокировкой с двойной проверкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking).
Ниже простенький пример.

```
public void DoWork()
{
    //Your code goes here

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        var coat = human.Coar("2");

        if (!coat.SetOwner(human)) return;

        // some logic

        coat.SetOwner(null);
    });
}

public class Human
{
    //your code here
}

public class Coat
{        
    public Human Owner {get; private set; }

    private object _lockObject = new object();

    public bool SetOwner(Human owner)
    {
        if (Owner != null) return false;
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            if (Owner != null) return false;

            Owner = owner;
            return true;
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: В данном случае код же вроде так и работает...А моя версия перевод, наверно зря. А как тут подобное использовать? Поставить flag на User(используется не используется) и если используется, то попробовать еще раз? flag в User включить можно, но во всех последующих методах в конце нужно поставить изменение этого флага на обратный...

Comment: [Пример](https://gist.github.com/Markeli/c2d27dcc6757de1b05e21c22eece0f6c)

Comment: И в каждый требуемый метод обращения к объекту передавать ссылку на того, кто его вызывает, а внутри сделать проверку, имеет ли он право сейчас это делать.

Comment: Репутация уже есть, но вроде бы и ответ вышел неплохой. Ещё бы код перенести из гиста в сам ответ, выйдет совсем хорошо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сделано.

Comment: @Markeli ага, спасибо. Плюс поставил ещё в прошлый раз)